# Add text to value of textarea on blur without jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html

So, I have a textarea in a form that records comments. I am attempting to append the identity of the user entering the comment to the end of the comment when entered.

Here is the PHP that checks the user session and gets the name of the user:

```
<?php 
    //getting username - displays John Doe
    $user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $firstname = $user->getUser()->getFirstname();
    $lastname = $user->getUser()->getLastname();
    $append = " [name](by ".$firstname." ".$lastname.")[/name]";
?>
```

The JavaScript that should be appending to the value on blur:

```
<script>
    function addedcomment(){
        var commentby = document.getElementById("#history_comment").value;
        var commentby = commentby + '<?php echo $append; ?>';
        document.getElementById('#history_comment').value = commentby;
    }
</script>
```

The textarea that comments are entered into:

```
<textarea name="history[comment]" rows="3" cols="5" style="height:6em; width:99%;" id="history_comment" onBlur="addedcomment()"></textarea>
```

The code appears on the page exactly in the order and manner that it has been shown here, so the PHP sets the value of $append before the JavaScript appears. I am getting three errors in the dom console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
addedcomment
onblur
```

The CMS I am using works with Prototype, so jQuery does not work all of the time (it seems it is selectively called in) even in noConflict mode.

Things I have tried:

```
Putting the JS below the textarea.
onblur vs onBlur
jQuery solution
```

Comment: Take a quick look through your page.  Do you use the `history_comment` id more than once?

Comment: @SimplyCraig What do you mean with `jQuery notation`? I don't see any jQuery.

Comment: @jeroen `$("#history_comment")` = jQuery notation.  `document.getElementById("history_comment")` = JavaScript.  So he mixed the two with `document.getElementById("#history_comment")`.

Comment: @SimplyCraig Okay, I didn't make the connection between a css selector and jQuery...

Comment: @jeroen I suppose he could have just been using css selector, but never the less that isn't used for JavaScript :)

Comment: I see now, yes, I had tried jQuery first and thought to leave in the #, but I guess it is superfluous when using JavaScripts getElementById since you are already targeting an id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are adding an un-needed "`#`" symbol. `document.getElementById()` requires only the name of the element's id (`history_comment`). The error is basically telling you that it can't get the property "`value`" of something that doesn't exist, i.e an element with the id of "`#history_comment`".
You don't need a jQuery solution, what you have here is fine except for the typos.

Comment: Funny he says without jQuery but uses jQuery notation. :P

Comment: Where do I use jQuery notation? Are you looking at the PHP code and thinking it is jQuery? @user3412847 - your solution worked, and did not contain any misinformation. Selecting your answer as the winner.

Answer (score 4):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

That is because there is no element with the ID "#history_comment". Only one with the ID "history_comment".

Also, changing a textarea's value works by changing its .innerHTML opposed to .value.
Same for reading the value from a textarea.

Why do you want to do this via Javascript?
Wouldn't it be better to do that after the post is submitted via PHP?
The way you are doing it right now, if I "blur" the textarea several times the text you add gets added several times.

Comment: The CMS I am using posts to controller files that are very complex, and this I felt was just the simpler, more elegant method. The individuals entering comments are employees who will be trained on how to enter comments correctly. Also, trying to use .innerHTML did not work, .value did.

Comment: Did changing "#id" to "id" fix your issue?

Comment: Yes, but I had to convert .innerHTML back to .value to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Just to continuation to above Answers...

Native JavaScript api document.getElementById just takes id as is where Jquery require the shortcut notations like '#', '.' internally it will use same native api like document.getElementById.

And as text area is a input element, it would have value property, where for other document elements like div, span table would innerHTML property. Even input elements will have innerHTML property but will just return empty.